# Android Volley onSending

Tags: android, android-volley, asynchttpclient

On Andriod, I'm trying to change the framework from AsyncHttpClient to Volley. There's a call back method **onStart** in **AsyncHttpClient** which helps me do something before I receive the response from the server. (Such as notifying the user to wait.)

I'd like to implement this functionality by Volley, but I didn't find a similar call back to implement. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: You would do this in the code before you send the volley request

Comment: @Populus do you mean before I call RequestQueque.add() or some other places?

Answer (score 0):

In [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/Response.java) there are two types of callbacks:

```
/** Callback interface for delivering parsed responses. */
public interface Listener<T> {
    /** Called when a response is received. */
    public void onResponse(T response);
}

/** Callback interface for delivering error responses. */
public interface ErrorListener {
    /**
     * Callback method that an error has been occurred with the
     * provided error code and optional user-readable message.
     */
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error);
}
```

There is no AsyncHttpClient `onStart` callback equivalent.

Example:

```
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // handle response
    }
}, new ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // handle error
    }
});

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

request.setTag(TAG); // you can add tag to request
requestQueue.add(request); // add request to queue
requestQueue.cancelAll(TAG); // you can cancel request using tag
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using these two Listeners. It seems Volley is not good at handling the moment during sending a request and receiving the response, does it? I'd like to notify the user it's processing during this moment.